# Flutter build failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build

At the moment I'm learning Flutter.

Today I ran into this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource compilation failed
     C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Flutter\my-app\android\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:3:5-78: AAPT: error: invalid color.

     C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Flutter\my-app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
```

After searching for hours I already tried:

- Other gradle versions
- Other launcher_icon
- with or without settings_aar.gradle

At the same time this error occurred I also had a new file in the `android` folder called `settings_aar.gradle`. I don't know if this has any relation to the error above or if it's something else.

The `colors.xml` mentioned in the error above looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ic_launcher_background">lib/assets/launcher/logo.png</color>
</resources>
```

After the error, flutter continues with building the packages I guess. The first few do succeed until a second error occurrs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.droibit.customtabslauncher:launcher:1.4.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.github.droibit.plugins.flutter.customtabs:flutter_custom_tabs_release:1.0
      > Could not resolve com.github.droibit.customtabslauncher:launcher:1.4.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/droibit/customtabslauncher/launcher/1.4.0/launcher-1.4.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/github/droibit/customtabslauncher/launcher/1.4.0/launcher-1.4.0.pom?referrer'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

Again I have no idea if these two errors belong together.

My actual flutter version where I'm trying this is `1.17.5`
`flutter doctor -v` looks like this:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale de-CH)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at C:\Users\USERNAME\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (5 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\USERNAME\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\USERNAME\sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\USERNAME\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
```

And this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: MyApp
description: Some description

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  http: ^0.12.2
  flutter_html_view: ^0.5.12
  url_launcher: ^5.5.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.5
  add_2_calendar: ^1.4.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.2
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/assets/logo.jpg
    - lib/assets/logo.png


flutter_icons:
  ios: true
  android: true
  image_path_ios: "lib/assets/launcher/logo.jpg"
  image_path_android: "lib/assets/launcher/logo.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "lib/assets/launcher/logo.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "lib/assets/launcher/logo.png"
```

I know it's a pretty long question but I wanted to provide anything important. If anything else is required please tell me.

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. Figured it out.

1. Updated the package `flutter_launcher_icons` to version `^0.7.5`
2. Removed all icons in all drawable and mipmap folders. Also deleted colors.xml.
3. In `pubspec.yaml` replace the jpg launcher icon on android with a png.
4. Recreate the icons with the command `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`
5. Clean the project and run again

Did now compile/build without any errors.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You must try the `flutter clean` command. That should help fix the problem.

Comment: Already tried this several times and also `flutter pub cache repair`. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when i used adaptive_icon_background: "ffffff" instead of adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff" on pubspec.yaml file, hope it helps to someone facing this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with `:app:mergeDebugResources` on my Flutter app while working with flavors.
The flavor, which caused the error, had a empty `provider_path.xml` file. The file is located at `../android/app/src/[FLAVORNAME]/res/xml/provider_path.xml`
The working flavor's `provider_path.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

I simply copied the code in the empty file, run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and the build succeeded without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter build failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

There is no the only one way is getting the same error on multiple and different mistakes So I explained what I did a mistake I hope it will help
[mistake I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WocS.png)

so you have to make a folder name assets or else but not under **❌src/main/res**

Do like this click on the image given link(correct way)
Like this
[correct way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3hkP.png)

and then try to add some images then
update path resource and pub.yaml file images path where ever you used in code
now run

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter pub get
```